# what is difference between AMQP connector and JMS connector in mule?

Tags: queue, mule, messagebroker

I'm bit confused between AMQP and JMS when to use which connecter ? like if i have Rabbit MQ then go for AMQP and Active MA then JMS.

How can i identify the connecter based based on various customer/client Queues ?

Answer (score 0):

The AMQP connector uses the [AMQP protocol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Message_Queuing_Protocol) to connect to AMQP compatible message brokers. The JMS connector uses the Java JMS Standard client libraries for a message broker. RabbitMQ is an AMQP message broker, so you should use the AMQP connector to connect to it. RabbitMQ also provides JMS libraries, but unless you have a very strong reason to use them it would be advisable to use its native AMQP protocol. If you want to learn more about the differences see this answer: [Difference in RabbitMq and RabbitMq with JMS plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113250/difference-in-rabbitmq-and-rabbitmq-with-jms-plugin)

Comment: This is the right idea. Also when you are curious which connector to use based on customer needs, you should search Anypoint Exchange to learn if there is a specific connector for your broker.  Some of the brokers that have connectors are Kafka, IBM MQ, Azure Service Bus, and Solace.